# is there a way to count the number of items without useselector for redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

i am trying to count the total number of items in a cart, using redux here. I know for functional component, i can use the useselector filter to do it, but just wondering if i can do the same for class component. P.S I am knees deep in class component and i really dont want to change my whole structure to functional components to use the hooks,is there a way to do it?

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    cartItems: state.cart.cartItems
  });
 
  


class CartIcon extends React.Component{  
        
    render(){   //render the icon button, with style, title and redirect to cart page( to be replaced with shopping cart icon)
       
     
        const item =this.props.cartItems;
        const qty=0
        for(i=0;i<item.length;i++){
         console.log("the item of " + item[i].name + "::" + item[i].qty)
            qty += item[i].qty;
        }
        console.log(qty)
        //console.log(item.length)
    
        return(
            
       <View style= {{padding : 5}}>
           <View style={{position :'absolute', height :35, width :30, borderRadius :25 , backgroundColor : '#ffffff' ,right : 10, 
           top:-12 , alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',zIndex :2000, }}>
               <Text style={{color :'blue', fontWeight :'bold' , top :25, right: 15, fontSize:18,borderRadius:30}}> {item.length}</Text>

            <Icon name="cart" size ={30} style ={{bottom : 9}} onPress ={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart')}
            />

           </View>
       </View>
         
        );
    }
}

 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withNavigation(CartIcon)); //export class
```

Comment: What's the issue with your code? Did you get the correct count of the items?

Comment: You are already using connect, which is the class equivalent to useSelector. So what's the issue?

Comment: btw, is js we use reduce to do an n-1 transformation on a list. So it would be `const qty = items.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.qty, 0)`

Comment: Also, you can change any one component to use the functional syntax without changing anything else. It's all the same to react.

Comment: the issue is that i dont get the exact count. If i add more than 1 instance of the same item, it will not get updated.I have to add another instance  of another object before it gets updated

Comment: i tried using this :const qty = items.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.qty, 0), however, if i add the quantity of the same item it doesnt show up, it wil only get reflected if it click on another object

Comment: Did you make sure your reducer doesn't mutate the state but creates a new array every time? Mutating the state would cause the kind of problems you're describing.